# Cross-platform SQL date difference function or query

Tags: sql, datetime, cross-platform

I have a table that has a datetime column and I need to retrieve records with a date within the previous hour, day, week, month etc.

One constraint is that I need to support Oracle, MySQL, DB2 and SQL SERVER.  Can I achieve this with one SQL query only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they all can handle datetimes differently, I'm going to guess you can't. You might be able to separate out the platform-specific stuff and swap it when the platform changes.

If you tell us more about this problem, we might be able to suggest something in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

User-defined functions.  Write your own `DATEDIFF`-equivalent for each RDBMS and abstract away the differences.

Comment: That may work across systems, but on some systems (I'm thinking SQL Server here), this approach will result in a performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

The ANSI SQL function would be `datediff()`. But I doubt all (especially older) SQL dialects support it.

Comment: IIRC, DATEDIFF is not supported by Oracle or DB2

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good reason to start up on a multi-tiered RDBMS-based-approach to retrieving data.